# GLib Hash Table - Unable to lookup key/value

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I'm trying to add malloc'd strings as keys and structs as values.  Each time is a new string but sometimes the text is the same so they should be treated as the same key. After adding the struct, I try to retrieve it but its not successful ("Failed add" below).  Also, my total count isn't getting updated and when the destroy calls free, I seg fault.  I've commented out the free for now.

```
GHashTable *heavyhitter= g_hash_table_new_full(NULL, g_str_equal, (GDestroyNotify) free_hh_key,(GDestroyNotify) free_hh_metadatarecords);
...
//Called multiple times:
void add_to_heavyhitter_hashtable(struct memory *mem, const char *file,int line, size_t sz) {   
struct hh_metadata_record *hh_metadata_record_toadd;

char *orig_key;
asprintf(&orig_key, "%s:%d", file, line);
char *effective_key = orig_key;

gpointer e_key_ptr = &effective_key;
gpointer hh_meta_ptr = &hh_metadata_record_toadd;

if (g_hash_table_lookup_extended(mem->heavyhitter_hashtable, &orig_key,
        &e_key_ptr, &hh_meta_ptr)) {
    printf("found\n");
    hh_metadata_record_toadd = hh_meta_ptr;
    printf("hh_metadata_record_toadd sz: %Zu\n", hh_metadata_record_toadd->sz);
} else {
    printf("not found\n");
    hh_metadata_record_toadd = hh_get_metadata_record_new(sz);

}

printf("Effective Key: %s\n", effective_key);

hh_metadata_record_toadd->count += 1;
hh_metadata_record_toadd->sz += sz;
mem->hh_total_count += 1;
mem->hh_total_size += sz;

g_hash_table_insert(mem->heavyhitter_hashtable, e_key_ptr,
        hh_metadata_record_toadd);
if(g_hash_table_lookup_extended(mem->heavyhitter_hashtable, effective_key, NULL, NULL ))
    printf("Succesfully added.\n");
else
    printf("Failed add\n");
printf("hash Table size: %Zu\n",g_hash_table_size(mem->heavyhitter_hashtable));
```

free function commented out for now:

```
void free_hh_key(gpointer a) {
    (void) a;
    printf("Freeing: %s\n", (char*) a);
    //free(a);
}
```

results:

```
not found
Effective Key: hhtest.c:49
Failed add
hash Table size: 1
not found
Effective Key: hhtest.c:49
Freeing: �' �'  �'  �/Y�
Failed add
hash Table size: 1
not found
Effective Key: hhtest.c:10
Freeing: �' �'  �'  �/Y�
Failed add
hash Table size: 1
```

Comment: Why do you create the HashTable with NULL for the hash_func? Your code is very hard to read btw., consider isolating the problematic code in an easy-to-read test case when asking such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the function type to: g_str_hash